# Springboot initialization depends on Liberty application.xml and showing classpath unknown exception

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I was trying to deploy my springboot application in WebSphere Liberty Core 18.0.0.2. I have two xml files in server - `server.xml` and `application.xml`. `application.xml` contains application specific configuration as below.

```
<library description="Oracle JDBC Library" id="OracleJDBCLib" name="OracleJDBCLib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/jdbc/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>
<jdbcDriver id="OracleProvider" libraryRef="OracleJDBCLib"/>

 <springBootApplication contextRoot="/provider" id="provider" location="provider-exec.war" type="war">
     <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleJDBCLib"  />
</springBootApplication>
```

And it is being included in server.xml

```
<include location="${server.output.dir}/application.xml" optional="true" onConflict="MERGE"/>
```

The issue is that springboot is taking this `application.xml` for bean initilization which should not happen. As per my understanding springboot war is self contained and it will not look for container specific configuraion.

In order to verify, I have renamed the `application.xml` to `springbootapp.xml` and it worked. App was working fine.

Kindly let me know if any configuration change required to restrict springboot to not to look for container specific configuration?

Comment: The `application.xml` is loaded as a properties file (yes properties can be defined in an XML to!). So what happens is spring tries to load `application.properties` / `application.xml` or `application.yml` to configure the properties. It finds the `application.xml` and assumes that that is the file needed to load the properties from. Solutions are, 1. rename it (as you already tried) 2. move it out of the root of the classpath (somewhere in `META-INF` for instance). ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not technically an answer, note that you can change the root context path of your Spring Boot application by declaring Spring Boot application properties `server.contextPath` or `server.servlet.contextPath` within an `<applicationArgument>` of your `<springBootApplication>`. Assuming a Spring Boot 2.0 application, try this.

```
<variable name="springBoot15AppArg1" value="--server.contextPath=/provider"/>
<variable name="springBoot20AppArg1" value="--server.servlet.contextPath=/provider"/>

<springBootApplication location="provider-exec.war">
    <applicationArgument>${springBoot20AppArg1}</applicationArgument>
</springBootApplication>
```

Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_sb_apparguments.html

Comment: I was using springboot 1.5. i have updated it to 2.0.0 for the changes to work.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the Spring Boot Reference Guide ([Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)) it will look for a file named `application.properties`. However what they don't tell you is that instead of `application.properties` this could also be an `application.xml`.

A [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object can be either loaded from a [`.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) or [`.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML-java.io.InputStream-) file. Spring (and thus Spring Boot) has implicit support for this.

So in short the configuration loading will detect `application.properties`, `application.yml` but also **`application.xml`**.

To fix you can do 2 things

1. Rename the file (as you did)
2. Move it out of the root of the classpath and place it in, for example `META-INF` instead.